# Android : App Crashed When Intent called inside the Recycler View

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview

i created a recycler view which display images and text from Sqlite in listview, To pass the Selected Item name to the New Activity i used Intent to pass data, But When My Intent was Called My App Was Crashed and it Shows `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.Context.startActivity(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference`

recyclerview

```
ArrayList<byte[]> list_image;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Context context;
private ArrayList<String> list_name;

 public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.listname.setText(String.valueOf(list_name.get(position)));

       
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(list_image.get(position), 0, list_image.get(position).length);
        ImageView image = holder.imgname;
        
        image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),AddItems.class);
                intent.putExtra("listname", String.valueOf(list_name.get(position)));
                context.startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }
```

Additems

```
  lisname = findViewById(R.id.listname_dis);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String dataTransmited=intent.getStringExtra("listname");
        lisname.setText(dataTransmited);
    }
```

logcat :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.Context.startActivity(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference
        at com.Karthi.check.CustomAdapter$1.onClick(CustomAdapter.java:76)
```

Comment: use view.getContext() instead of  context.startActivity(intent) while starting the activity i.e view.getContext().startActivity(intent)

Comment: Thanks bro, but if i use  view.getContext() it Doesnot Perform Any action, If i use  view.getContext(intent) then it Show the Error Msg`" expected  arguments but found one "`

Comment: view.getContext(intent) is incorrect syntax. You have to check AddItems activity than because when you trigger the intent activity will open.

Comment: Pass the context in the constructor of Recycler view from the activity and then use that context. Example in activity RecyclerView rv = new RecyclerView(getApplicationContext());

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Your Custom Adapter initlize  `private Activity activity;`

Then

```
public CustomAdapter(Activity activity,....){

 this.activity = activity;
......
.....
....
}


   use  activity.startActivity(intent); in your OnClickListerner


holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),AddItems.class);
                intent.putExtra("listname", String.valueOf(list_name.get(position)));
                activity.startActivity(intent);

            }
```

Also i ur main activity add

```
CustomAdapter ca = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,this,......)
```

Comment: there's no need to pass around context, you can get it from the view parameter

Answer (score 1):

**since your "context" is null Try this:**

```
view.getContext().startActivity(intent)
```

**instead of this:**

```
context.startActivity(intent)
```